# permutation problem-four main highways

Tags: combinatorics

There are four main highways from A to B and three from B to C.  In how many ways may one drive from A to C and return, going through B on both trips without travelling on the same road twice?

Can't understand the logic. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider how many choices you have at each step and use the multiplication principle.  When you go from A to B you have four, but coming back you can't  use the one you took before.